# Solutions to an equation of the form $x^n=x$ in a finite field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

I'm trying to count the number of solutions to an equation of the form $x^n=x$ in the finite field $F_{q^n}.$ 
In case of $n=q$, it's clear that every element of $F_q$, namely the base field, is a solution to this equation. 
I also know that $F_{q^n}-\{0\}$ is a cyclic multiplicative group of size $q^n-1$, and hence in order for $x^n=x$ to have a nontrivial answer, $(n-1,q^n-1) \neq 1$.
Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have correctly assessed that either $x=0$ or a solution of $x^{n-1}=1$. The multiplicative group of $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ is cyclic of order $q^n-1$. This may be a good time to recall the formula for the number of solutions of $x^\ell=1$ in a cyclic group of order $m$? Note: $x=1$ is always a solution. If you don't remember the formula you can try and recall it by studying the number of solutions to the congruence $ax\equiv0\pmod6$ for various $a$.

Comment: Also, this is nearly certainly a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can you send me the title of the question that you believe this one resembles? Thanks!

Comment: Gimme a moment. A special case was handled [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/175309/11619). I'm not sure whether the most general version was tagged finite fields, elementary number theory, or something else :-)

Comment: The basic duplicate will be one that describes that the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic.  As it happens, the converse of this is also true (and a frequent duplicate as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $x=0$ is always a solution. Next we assume $x \neq 0$ and the equation simplifies to $x^{n-1}=1$. Considering the fact that the multiplicative group $F_{q^n} - \{0\}$ is cyclic of size $q^n-1$, we have $x^{n-1}=1$ precisely when $x^{gcd(n-1,q^n-1)}=1$. Let $t=gcd(n-1,q^n-1)$; Assume $y$ is a generator for the cyclic group $F_{q^n} - \{0\}$, which clearly means $F_{q^n} - \{0\} = \{y^k | k=0,1,...,q^n-2\}$. This means we have to find elements $y^k$ such that $(y^k)^t=y^{kt}=1$. This happens if and only if $q^{n}-1$ divides $kt$. So let $A=\{k: 0\leq k \leq q^n-2,  q^{n}-1 | kt\}=\{k: 0\leq k \leq q^n-2,  \frac{q^{n}-1}{t} | k\}$. Considering $0$ is always a solution, it follows the number of solutions to $x^n=x$ equals $|A|+1=t+1$. 
(My special thanks to @Jyrki Lahtonen for his very helpful remarks.)

Comment: Good job. Because $t\mid q^n-1$ you can further observe that $q^n-1\mid kt$ if and only if $k$ is a multiple of $(q^n-1)/t$. This implies that $|A|=t$.

Comment: I immensely appreciate your help!! :)